# The button onclick in html has stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a website that using prompt popup to login. When I click the button, it didn't work. How to slove this problem?

Code here:

```
<style>
button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  let person = prompt("Please enter your username:", "");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    text = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else if (person == "hi" || person == "test" || person == "1234") {
    window.location.href = "youtube.com/c/呂殿下";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "youtube.com";
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Click me</button>
</body></html>
```

Comment: There's no button in your code

Comment: Don't replace your old questions with a new one just because you're question banned. Using edits as a way to evade the block isn't okay. Editing like that also invalidates existing answers people have put time and effort into. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/6296561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function had a couple of errors:

- single `=` in first `else if`
- no closing `}` for the else block

In order to make the branching visible, I am logging out the location instead of setting `window.location.href` for this example.

```js
var text;

function myFunction() {
  let person = prompt("Please enter your username:", "");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    text = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else if (person == "hi" || person == "test" || person == "1234") {
    console.log("setting href to sites.google.com/");
    //window.location.href = "sites.google.com/";
  } else {
    console.log("setting href to google.com");
    //window.location.href = "google.com";
    }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```